# How do publishers get their play store page to look like this?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play, publish

[image: Play Stor page of Jio India]

So for most of the time when you click on the publisher's name under the app name in play store, and you are taken to the publisher's play store page, it is just a list of all the apps they have published. But sometimes I see that some publishers have a very well organized page. Like they will have a cover photo, featured app, and then they will have all their apps listed under it. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by going to Google Play Console where all apps are listed(Means you find all your apps which are uploaded on that account).

From the side menu Navigate to the "Developer Page" like below image. and fill details then you will have your developer page like above image.

[image]

Hope it helps.